# ElasticSearch: How can I add mapping for array field?

Tags: elasticsearch

Sample document in elasticsearch:

```
{
    "name": "Tom",
    "hobbies": [
        {
            "hobby": "go for a walk"
        },
        {
            "hobby": "board games"
        }
    ]
}
```

Here is mapping added for "name":

```
{
    "person": {
         "_all": {
            "analyzer": "ik_max_word",
            "search_analyzer": "ik_max_word",
            "term_vector": "no",
            "store": "false"
        },
        "properties": {
            "name": {
                "type": "string",
                "store": "no",
                "term_vector": "with_positions_offsets",
                "analyzer": "ik_max_word",
                "search_analyzer": "ik_max_word",
                "include_in_all": "true",
                "boost": 8
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Problem: How do I add mapping for hobbies.hobby? I want to specify this field for analyzer -> ik_max_word

Answer (score 1):

Okay, according to [Object datatype description](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/object.html), it should be done like this:

```
{
    "person": {
        "_all": {
            "analyzer": "ik_max_word",
            "search_analyzer": "ik_max_word",
            "term_vector": "no",
            "store": "false"
        },
        "properties": {
            "name": {
                "type": "string",
                "store": "no",
                "term_vector": "with_positions_offsets",
                "analyzer": "ik_max_word",
                "search_analyzer": "ik_max_word",
                "include_in_all": "true",
                "boost": 8
            },
            "hobbies": {
                "properties": {
                    "hobby": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "store": "no",
                        "term_vector": "with_positions_offsets",
                        "analyzer": "ik_max_word",
                        "search_analyzer": "ik_max_word",
                        "include_in_all": "true",
                        "boost": 8
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```